# Multiplying Matrices and getting all possible solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

So I have the following exercise
(Sorry for the terrible formatting)

Mx = B where

M=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6\\ 
7 & 8 & 9  
\end{bmatrix}

B=
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 \\ 
6 & 5 & 4\\ 
9 & 8 & 7 
\end{bmatrix}

I solve for x
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

I'm having trouble getting all the solutions which is given as

Assuming a,b,c are the free variables
\begin{bmatrix}
a-1 & b & 1+c \\ 
2-2a & 1-2b & -2c\\ 
a & b & c 
\end{bmatrix}

How was this last matrix achieved?

Comment: $\det{M}=0$, so there isn't a unique solution. How do I know $\det{M}=0$? It was the one of the first matrices I tried for practice when I learnt about determinants... notice that subtracting columns gives two of the form $(1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To break it down one at a time, take the system for the first column $Mx = b_1$ so that $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6\\ 
7 & 8 & 9  
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3\\6\\9\end{bmatrix}$$

That is,
$$a_1+2a_2+3a_3 = 3 \\4a_1+5a_2+6a_3 = 6\\ 7a_1+8a_2+9a_3 = 9
$$

Solving, with respect to $a_3$ as free variable: $a_2 = 2-2a_3$, and $a_1 = -\frac{a_2}{2} = a_3-1$. That is,

$$x = \begin{bmatrix}a-1\\2-2a\\a \end{bmatrix}$$

Computationally, $M x_z = 0$ has nontrivial solutions since rank = 2, kernel = 1. Thus $x_z = a(1, -2, 1)$ by directly solving $M x_z = 0$, and $x_b = (-1, 2, 0)$ by solving $M x_b = b$.